# Unity CharacterController steps on colliders with 0 Step Offset

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics

I'm moving my `CharacterController` with the `Move()` method and for some reason it **still steps on colliders** even though its **Step Offset is 0**.

Here's how the game looks:

- Every objects' **root is at Y = 0**, so their colliders' **center is offsetted**.
- the floor is made up from tiles, with `QuadColliders`.
- there stairs have just a `BoxCollider`
- the player got a `CharacterController`

[image]

**Here are the components:**

CharacterController, stairs' collider, and the floor's collider, where the floor itself is scaled to (2, 2, 1):

[image]

I've checked the collisions with `OnControllerColliderHit()` and:

- After hitting play the **Y is 0**, as it should be.
- After moving a bit, without colliding with anything the **Y changes from 0 to 0.079**.
- Then if I start running towards a `BoxCollider`, after some time it **steps on it incrementally** under half a second.

  - *(The collider has a 0.8 height, so controller's Y changes to 0.8)*

I'm a bit lost, thanks in advance for all the help! :)

[image]

Comment: Try playing around with your skin width.

Comment: @Evorlor in what ways exactly? :| The docs says that having it around 10% of the radius is good. It's 10% right now.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? How are you moving your character? I may be wrong, but I think the problem here may be your character controller settings.

Comment: @C.G.Yeudiel I call characterController.Move() with a Vector3 whose Y is always zero (I work with Vector2-s in game logic, so I just convert it before passing it to Unity)
My goal is to make my character's Y stay at zero :D

Comment: @Tudvari Hmm, alright, it may be a mix of many different variables. It's hard to tell without code, even though I don't think the problem comes from the code itself. In fact, I think this is expected behavior (except for the stair). According to the docs, the Step Offset can affect the way your character controller behaves, and it doesn't recommend using a value lower than 0.1 (0.4 for a 2 meter tall humanoid). Your character is 3 meters tall so maybe that's the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official api of unity has a vague explanation of each parameter. After testing I got the relatively correct meaning of the parameters.

[image]

In this collision situation, as long as the hemisphere of the capsule is higher than the upper plane of the box, it will cross the box. Skinwidth will **expand** your capsule body, The capsule is **raised** due to the collision between the capsule and the ground, So it will cross the box.

So in fact, the height that the capsule body can cross is the **larger** of the value determined by step offset and physical properties.

The maximum height your capsule can cross is 0.88(capsule's radius + skin width)(>0.8), What you describe is expected performance.

Suggestion:

Reduce the radius of the capsule to make it fit the character better. I think (0.5~0.6) will be fine.

edit:

1. Why use radius: When the collision occurs on a spherical surface, the force vector points to the center of the sphere, It will bring an upward component, causing the capsule to lift.
2. Why 0.5-0.6 would fit better the character: There is no mandatory standard. But the character's collision box should fit as close to the torso as possible, The example in your picture looks a bit too large, which leads to a series of problems that are not intuitive. Your question is one of them.

Sorry I'm not a native English speaker, some words are used incorrectly, have been re-edited, hope it helps.

Comment: Could you rephrase it a bit? What is exactly the surface portion? I guess 0.88 is radius + skin width. Why did you use radius? And why do you think 0.5-0.6 would fit better the character? I have a higher than visual size so it can be more easily :|

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it's clearer now! :) Good job on figuring out this issue, I reduced the radius thus lowering the height of the hemisphere and now it works! :)) Thanks again!

Comment: For all who's interested: I posted this issue on Unity's forums, maybe they will do something about it: https://forum.unity.com/threads/make-charactercontrollers-properties-clearer-more-usable-and-remove-unexpected-behaviour.1274843/